# Can lambda expressions in java be still compacted

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have this code.

```
public class  TypeInterface{
    public static void main(String [] args){
                 StringLengthLambda myLambda =  s -> s.length();
                 System.out.print(myLambda.getLength("abc"));
    }

    interface StringLengthLamdba{
              int getLength(String s);
    }
}
```

Can this code be modified to

`StringLengthLambda myLambda = s.length()`
or
any other way to shorten this?

Comment: `myLambda = String::length` which is not shorter than `myLambda =  s -> s.length()`. You can’t write an expression referring to an `s` without declaring `s`.

Comment: @Holger you should probably just answer that

Comment: @lucasvw: that’s a bit thin for an answer. Which might be a general problem of this kind of question.

Comment: @Holger true, but it looks like Mureinik just posted exactly that as an answer anyway... lol.

Answer (score 4):

I can't think of any way to write a shorter lambda, but you could use a method reference:

```
StringLengthLambda myLambda = String::length;
```

Comment: Why would they have thought of adding "s->" in a first place if the compiler knew already as to what type interface it expects.

Comment: @krupalpatel86 but how else would you know the name of what you're operating on? What if you want to compare it to a different object?

Comment: @lucasvw : compiler can assume whatever is the new undefined variable on the right hand side of the "->"  .  myLambda = s.length()
 =~ s -> s.length()

Comment: @krupalpatel86 The compiler can't infer undefined variables unless you explicitly define it: `s -> s.length()`; that's why method references exist.

Comment: @Mureinik you could add that a method reference is not de-sugared to a method, while a lambda expression is.

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need the package protected interface `StringLengthLambda`. You could just go with:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    Function<String, Integer> myLambda =  String::length;
    System.out.print(myLambda.apply("abc"));
}
```

If you want different "length-computation-methods" on `"abc"` you could even go with:

```
public class TypeInterface {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        print(String::length);
    }

    private static void print(StringLengthLambda myLambda) {
        System.out.print(myLambda.getLength("abc"));
    }

    @FunctionalInterface
    interface StringLengthLambda {
        int getLength(String s);
    }
}
```